# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre android:layout_gravity y android:gravity?

Tags: android, android-layout

Cuando se diseña, por ejemplo, un `TextView view` en Android, se le pueden asignar las propiedades `android:layout_gravity="left"` y/o `android:gravity="left"`

¿Cual es la diferencia entre utilizar `layout_gravity` o `gravity` sobre el `View`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La diferencia entre ellas, es que la `layout_gravity` es la gravedad de la vista respecto a su padre y `gravity` es la gravedad interna, por ejemplo si la vista es un `TextView` es donde quieres que el texto se muestre, alineación etc...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen extraída de [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/gravity-and-layout-gravity-on-android)

Answer (score 2):

Ya fue contestada en ingles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/gravity-and-layout-gravity-on-android

Te la traduzco:

> Sus nombres deberian ayudarte:
>
> **android:gravity** setea la gravedad del contenido de la vista en la que es usado.
> **android:layout_gravity** setea la gravedad del PADRE de la vista o del layout.
>
> [Aquí tienes un ejemplo.](https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/14/how-to-position-views-properly-in-layouts/)